# How to investigate Failed to fetch?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I'm investigating a problem that we have with failed to fetch errors. Only a few users seem to get this and not all the time, but the majority is from the same company.

There is a 4x retry loop in the code, but it just fails 4 times.

The users are advised to click CTRL+F5 and it seems to sort it out, at least for a while.

We had a week without any issues, then we updated the system and the problem started again.

Google is full of failed-to-fetch problems, but it's hard to find a relevant one, especially as we cannot reproduce the issue.

We get the error reports in Sentry and we can see events like

```
Fetch Save [200]  time: 14.41.03
ui.click
ui.click
Navigation from: url to url     time 14.41.34
exception: type-error: failed to fetch    time 14.41.40
```

Most users are using an updated version of chrome, but we have tried other browsers.

Any help would be appreciated. I have the source code and can make changes.

Thanks

```
async function doFetch(input, init) {
    //console.log('doFetch', input);
    const response = await fetch(input, init);

    if (!response.ok && (response.status != 304)) {
        throw new Error(response.status+' - '+response.statusText);
    }

    const responseForError = response.clone();
    try {
        return await response.json();
    } catch (e) {
        e.extraInfo = {
            responseHead: String(await responseForError.text()).substr(0, 200),
        };

        throw e;
    }
}

export async function fetchJSON(input, init = {}) {
    const _init = {
        ...init,
        headers: {
            ...init.headers,
            Accept: 'application/json',
            //'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
        },
        method: init.method || 'GET',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    };

    const response = await retryFetchLoop(input, _init);
    checkResponseForError(response);

    return response;
}

async function retryFetchLoop(URL, init) {
    let retryCounter = (((init.method == 'GET') || init.canRetry) ? 4 : 1);
    let retryDelay = 0;

    while (retryCounter > 0) {
        try {

            return await doFetch(URL, init);

        } catch (error) {
            if ((error.message == 'Failed to fetch')
                || String(error.message).match(/NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource/)
                || String(error.message).match(/Network request failed/)
                || String(error.message).match(/Network Error/)
                || ((error.response || {}).status == 502)
                || ((error.response || {}).status == 504)
            ) {
                if (retryCounter > 1) {
                    retryCounter--;
                    retryDelay += 500;

                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, retryDelay));

                    continue;
                }

                const logErr = new ConnectionError('Failed to fetch');
                logErr.extraInfo = {
                    URL,
                    OriginalError: error.message,
                };
                errorLogger(logErr);

                throw error;
            }

            error.extraInfo = {
                ...(error.extraInfo || {}),
                URL,
            };
            errorLogger(error);

            throw error;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say start by showing us your code, the site you're sending the request to, what options you're sending with the fetch and the actual errors that fetch gets.  We always have a much, much better chance of helping if we can see the actual code in question.

Comment: This sounds like a caching problem, since it happens after you update things and CTRL+F5 loads the page without local cache. With zero specifics about the HTTP calls themselves and the associated errors, or the relevant code, we won't be able to help you though.

Comment: I have added some code. I don't have the failing calls, apart from what I see in Sentry.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to CORS. Something added _sm_byp to the query parameters and caused a redirect. That redirect triggered Access-Control-Allow-Origin to fail.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: (ctx) => {
        return '*';
    },
     ...
}));
```